# Database using JSP and Receiving an Error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have an issue in the JSP file that I have made when trying to add information to the database. I keep getting a **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP:**  error when I try and execute and it points at this code block. I'm assuming it has something to do with the setAutoCommit statement, but I am not sure as it also shows a nullPointerException as well. Any insight would be helpful.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://example:3306/database";
    String username = "test";
    String password = "test";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stm=null;

    String classPath = "sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbc0dbcDriver";
    try{
        Class.forName(classPath);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        }catch(Exception exc){

            out.println(exc.toString());

        }

%>

<center><a href="example3-1.jsp">View Movies</a></center><br>
<%
    String MovieTitle=request.getParameter("MovieTitle");
    String MainActor=request.getParameter("MainActor");
    String MainActress=request.getParameter("MainActress");
    String Rating=request.getParameter("Rating");

    String query1 = null;

    query1 = "INSERT INTO MovieTitles (MovieTitle,MainActor,MainActress,Rating) VALUES('"+MovieTitle+"','"+MainActor+"','"+MainActress+"','"+Rating+"')";

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    stm = conn.createStatement();
    try{
        stm.executeUpdate(query1);
        conn.commit();
        out.println("<center><h2>A new movie has been added.</h2>");
        out.println("<a href=example3-2.jsp>Add another Movie</a></center>");
        }catch(Exception exc){
            conn.rollback();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        %>

            <script>
                alert("Entry failed. Please retry.");
            </script>
    <%}%>
<%
    if(stm != null){ stm.close();}
    conn.close();
%>
```

Comment: Can you please post the full jsp syntax at least java part..

Comment: The connection object is null here.

Comment: I posted the whole code this time, since it got chopped off before. The same issue still persists however. I checked if all statements were closed properly as well.

Comment: sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbc0dbcDriver 0->o and its a mysql server but why you are using odbc driver?

Comment: Such a tiny error and could potentially mess up the rest. However, I just fixed that and tried it out again and no luck this time either.

Comment: Basically, I'm just trying to enter data into a table using mysql and since i'm not totally comfortable with jsp, I chose to use that to see if it worked after some research with mysql.

Comment: @starlord figured it out. I had the wrong driver setup for the application purpose. It was supposed to be "com.mysql.jdcbc.driver"

Comment: I have given that answer long back.. no probs, now you got it. :)

Comment: @starlord since you helped me out and did include, the answer, I accepted the answer as correct by you : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//STEP : Register JDBC driver

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

//STEP : Open a connection

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conn object is not declared/initialized-

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

Link to know more about establishing a connection-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

create statement method throws `SQLException`. Add the createStatement() method inside `try` block

```
try {
stm = conn.createStatement();
 ............
 ............

}
```